# Manga with a girl who bonds with gods to fight other gods. She has long blonde hair and a gold helmet

Tags: story-identification, manga

It was about a girl who all gods loved naturally, she goes to school with all these kids and they would infused together with the god they bonded with when they needed to fight other gods that went bad or rogue (these gods, when bad, looked like stone). She had long blonde hair and when she transformed, she had a gold helmet with wings on it.

I think they called her white flowers sama. something like that.

Comment: @Jenayah - I've reversed your edit because it's not immediately clear whether the white flowers are called "*sama*" or whether she was called "*white flowers sama*"...

Comment: @Valorum ah, fair enough. Sama is a title or something in Japanese, now that you mention it. Thanks for the rollback then!

Comment: Are there other characters, especially male characters? How do the "gods" look like (humanoid/mecha/small tools/formless/monster)? How does the art style look like (shonen-style/shojo-style/realistic)? What is the most suitable genre (shonen/shojo/romance/etc...)?

Comment: I would believe it falls under school life and action/romance. There is a group of them and gods are humanoid/monster some are small tools and shojo-style

Comment: Also, regarding the last sentence, I assumed you mean the girl is called White Flower-*sama* Consider [edit]ing the post to include your previous comment, so that everyone can notice it easily :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is [Kami-sama Gakuen @ Armeria](https://myanimelist.net/manga/35519/Kamisama_GakuenArmeria).

> *Yanagawa Rikka is a student from Armeria—a school where only 30 students are attending. Little did Yanagawa realized that she was actually the chosen one by God to protect the world from the almighty, God of the Death.*

[image]

Comment: I've removed the copyright-infringing link from your answer. I've also taken the liberty of adding in a brief description of the property